# Как открыть специальную страницу с фикс. размером?

Tags: c++builder

Здравствуйте, допустим у меня есть чат - мне нужно что бы при открытии программы на (с++ или с++builder или c#)
Открывалась страница с фиксированным размером, к примеру 800х1000 и с моим чатом в окне этой самой программы, как это сделать, подскажите пожалуйста (в c++ билдер, нулячий)

Comment: Я правильно понял что основная проблема - это при запуске программы создать окно фиксированного размера? Просто в WinAPI есть методы позволяющие создать окно не только фиксированного размера но и в фиксированном месте экрана. Если есть возможность то лучше на шарпе, там это апи инкапсулированно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот код на C# который создает окно размером в половину ширины и в половину высоты экрана.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
//...//
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height / 2,
                                System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width / 2);
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size((System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width / 2),
                                                (System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height / 2));
//...//
    }
}
```